# MotionLayout (Android) Not Updating Design View

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have been using MotionLayout to create an intro animation for my app, but I’m having some odd behavior in design view when making changes.  Ultimately everything works, but when I make a change (on design view only) the change doesn’t show in design view until I click back and forth from the “start” and “end” constraint sets.  As an example, if I remove a constraint from a view on the “end” set, it will look like nothing happened, but if I click on start and then end, the change will now be shown.

I tried this on several machines, and all seem to have this behavior.  I tried several versions of Android Studio, and searched around, but I can’t seem to find anything.  Is there something that I am missing?